# I am having trouble correcting the syntax of these double and single quotes in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble with the syntax of the second line, in particular, figuring out the proper quotes around `$row[type]` relative to the rest of the statement.  Thanks!

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_result)) {
    $row["done"] == "checked" ? $selected= " selected = ""{$row['type']}"" : $selected="";

    $type_options .= sprintf("<option value='%s' ".$selected.">%s</option>".PHP_EOL, $row2["type_name"], $row2["type_name"]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row["done"] == "checked" ? $selected= " selected=\"{$row['type']}\"" : $selected="";
```

That should do

Answer (score 0):

While your solution uses less lines, I find it very hard to read (and debug!)...here is an alternative:

```
$selected="";
if($row["done"] == "checked") {
    $selected = 'selected = "'.$row["type"].'"';
}
//ETC ETC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is without syntax error:

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_result)) {
$row["done"] == "checked" ? $selected = " selected = ".$row["type"]."" : $selected="";

$type_options .= sprintf("<option value='%s'".$selected.">%s</option>".PHP_EOL.", ".$row2['type_name'].", ".$row2['type_name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be:

```
$selected = ($row["done"] == "checked") ? " selected=\"{$row['type']}\"" : "";
```